# symplectic form, tautological 1-form and DeRham cohomology

Tags: symplectic-geometry, de-rham-cohomology

There's a question in Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifold that asks to prove that the Grassmannian product of a symplectic form is not exact. However, isn't this incorrect if there exists a tautological 1-form on the manifold ?

Comment: I think you forget the compacity condition (the manifold has to be compact). If there is a primitive to your symplectic form, it allows you to tell that your manifold is non-compact.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm kind of new to the subject, can you point me to which theorem states that compact symplectic manifold doesn't have tautological 1-form?

Comment: Precisely the question you are studying in Lee's book (without forgetting this compact hypothesis).